# How to just clone text using jQuery's clone()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clone an element's text, say an h1. I'm using jQuery's clone(), but I just want to copy the text and not the h1 tag so I can insert it into an h3 tag. I've tried using text() after the .clone(), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you're after, but it sounds like you just want to set the text to the same thing, like this:

```
$("h3").text($("h1").text());
```

---

The alternative is to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of the `<h1>`, which you can do directly like this:

```
$("h3").append($("h1").text());
```

But, as @[bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) points out below this can be dangerous in some situations, let's take a simple one:

```
<h1>&lt;script&gt;alert("hi, I'm malicious script");&lt;/script&gt;</h1>
```

[You can see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gqyHf/)...you can imagine how this could be problematic with some nasty script.

Comment: You definitely want the second one. The first one takes the text of an element and uses it as HTML, so if there are `<` or `&` characters in it they'll get treated as markup (potentially resulting in an XSS security hole).

Comment: @bobince - definitely a valid point, I changed the order above, along with an illustration so people can see the exploit scenario you're talking about.